# How can I increase my Temple Run multiplier?

Tags: temple-run

In Temple Run, I have all the objectives completed, but my multiplier is only 35.  My friend's multiplier is at 42 and she doesn't have all the objectives.

How can I get a higher permanent multiplier?

Comment: I double checked and I have all of the objectives. As for the same version I have yet to find out. Is there any other ways to up your perminant multiplier?

Comment: It's been a while since I upgraded this game, but I vaguely remember completing an objective more than once (a second time after an update). This could lead to a multiplier higher than 35.  I won't call that an answer - just conjecture. Clearly this is a widely observed phenomenon.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure both of you are running the same version. Temple Run has been updated after release with new objectives, so make sure you're running a recent version.

Secondly, make sure you've really got all objective cleared. If you have an objective (or objectives) missing, you'll see a "Next Objective" message after each run. You can always check the objective list on the main menu.

Answer (score 2):

Filling the coin meter by picking up coins increases your multiplier.  If your friends have multipliers over 40 without completing all objectives, it could be explained by performance during the run (number of times the coin bar was filled).

There are also a number of published hacks for this game.  Assuming your friends aren't the hacking type?

Note: Experimentally I don't find the coin bar to increase the multiplier with the current version of the game.  Several site and videos suggest that this multiplier no longer applies in the current version.  As the first answerer points out, it could still be though that your friends are using an older version.

Comment: Filling the coin meter will not grant permanent multipliers, in any case, they'd never show on the final screen

Comment: I see with a deeper read of your question that it was targeted only at permanent multipliers. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not use the tutorial mode hack**

Any objective you complete using "tutorial mode hack" will not increase your multiplier, you are actually making the objectives unavailable for completion during actual games. Attain your objective legitimately and you will be able to increase your multiplier up to 46 times.